# How do I Insert a Previously Created SQLite Database into a Xamarin.Android App?

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

My question seems simple, but it is hard for me and I can't find answers anywhere else.

I've created a database in `SQLite` and I want to add it to my `Xamarin.Android` application. How can I achieve this? I initially want only one column showing on the screen. Then when the user clicks on one of the items, the next screen should show all the other data of the selected item (you can think it of as dictionary).

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: this is the problem buddy that i don't know how to do this.

Comment: So what have you tried? Code samples?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty substantial feature of an app - to add local storage and display it in the UI. What you need to do is start looking at the Xamarin docs for adding SQLite to your app. Then you need to look at how to display data. I would suggest using SQLite.Net PCL and perhaps even Xamarin.Forms. If you have a *specific* coding problem that you need help with, then that would be a better question for stackoverflow.